# Adding multiple proximity alerts to location manager

Tags: android, android-intent, locationmanager

i am having trouble with adding more then one proximity alert to my location listener. i already searched the internet but found nothing helpful. please let me know if i am doing some thing wrong . here is my code snippet

```
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.addProximityAlert(30.0, 70.0, 1000, -1, PendingIntent.getActivity(Map.this, 0, new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")), 0));

    locationManager.addProximityAlert(40.0, 50.0, 1000, -1, PendingIntent.getActivity(Map.this, 10, new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")),0));
```

From my emulator control when i give 30.0 and 70.0 nothing happen but when i give 40.0 and 50.0 my pending intent trigger. i want to add both these locations to my location manager's proximity alert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `BroadcastReceiver` and `BroadcastMessages` to manage more thant one proximity alert. When you add the second alert `40.0, 50.0`, you overwrite the first alert.
A good solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4952165/2015318).